# How to reset bitcoin testnet / signet / regtest in newest bitcoin core

Tags: wallet, source-code

The testnet data directory is not ~/.bitcoin but rather ~/.bitcoin/testnet3. ~/.bitcoin holds the data for the main Bitcoin blockchain.

the files are still there but deleting them wont work anymore.

so how do i delete all block history and transaction history now from testnet /regtest/signet ?

if i delete the files you mentioned nothing is happening . still get 3 years and 8 months loading ....

all help is welcome thanks in advance

Comment: Delete `blocks` and `chainstate`

Comment: yes i know if i do that and than try again nothing happens the memory just stays the same its not that simple . even if i command make after deleting and try again its still the same memory, i also deleted all chainparamseeds,.h and in chainparams adjust the minchainwork etc .

Comment: If you delete just the chain's data, it will obviously download it again from the network. Are you by any chance asking about how to create a _new_ empty chain instead?

Comment: im asking exactly what i was asking it has nothing to do with an new chain ,just how to delete the testnet chain data.

Comment: is there anybody who can help? please